# Python Pandas ffill or bffill with multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-conditions, fillna, ffill

I have a dataset like below :

```
condition=[None,None,None,'condtion1',None,None,None,'conditon2',None,None,None]
add_val = [None,None,None,10,None,None,None,20,None,None,None]
df=pd.DataFrame({'event_condition':condition,'add_col':add_val})
```

[image]

I want to fillna of add_col in terms of condition.

When I meet condition 1 of event_condition, I want to ffill with value of 10 in a separate column called 'on_condition1'. It should not be changed for condition2.
When I meet condition 2 of event_conditon, I want to ffill with value of 20 in a separate column called 'on_condition2' It should not be changed for condition1.
Before meeting these conditions, I want to back fill with 0.

I tried groupby method but it did not work :

```
 df.groupby(df['event_condition'].eq(cond).cumsum())['add_col'].ffill()
```

[image]

It will be like this :

```
condition=[None,None,None,'condtion1',None,None,None,'conditon2',None,None,None]
add_val = [None,None,None,10,None,None,None,20,None,None,None]
on_cond1=[0,0,0,None,10,10,10,None,10,10,10]
on_cond2=[0,0,0,None,0,0,0 ,None,20,20,20]
df=pd.DataFrame({'event_condition':condition,'add_col':add_val,'on_condition1':on_cond1,'on_condition2':on_cond2})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#create Series with non NaNs rows by event_condition
s = df.dropna(subset=['event_condition']).set_index('event_condition')['add_col']

#for each value add new column
for k, v in s.items():
    #new column name
    col = f'on_{k}'
    #test all rows after match condition
    m = df['event_condition'].eq(k).cummax()
    #test rows for non NaNs
    m1 = df['event_condition'].notna()
    #set new column by 2 masks
    df[col] = np.select([m1, m], [np.nan,v], 0)

print (df)
   event_condition  add_col  on_condtion1  on_conditon2
0             None      NaN           0.0           0.0
1             None      NaN           0.0           0.0
2             None      NaN           0.0           0.0
3        condtion1     10.0           NaN           NaN
4             None      NaN          10.0           0.0
5             None      NaN          10.0           0.0
6             None      NaN          10.0           0.0
7        conditon2     20.0           NaN           NaN
8             None      NaN          10.0          20.0
9             None      NaN          10.0          20.0
10            None      NaN          10.0          20.0
```

Another idea with forward fillig:

```
s = df.dropna(subset=['event_condition']).set_index('event_condition')['add_col']
for k, v in s.items():
    col = f'on_{k}'
    m = df['event_condition'].eq(k)
    m1 = df['event_condition'].notna()
    df[col] = np.select([m1, m.cummax()], 
                        [np.nan, df['add_col'].where(m).ffill()], 0)

print (df)
   event_condition  add_col  on_condtion1  on_conditon2
0             None      NaN           0.0           0.0
1             None      NaN           0.0           0.0
2             None      NaN           0.0           0.0
3        condtion1     10.0           NaN           NaN
4             None      NaN          10.0           0.0
5             None      NaN          10.0           0.0
6             None      NaN          10.0           0.0
7        conditon2     20.0           NaN           NaN
8             None      NaN          10.0          20.0
9             None      NaN          10.0          20.0
10            None      NaN          10.0          20.0
```

With baxk fillig, is necsary change order for cumulative max:

```
s = df.dropna(subset=['event_condition']).set_index('event_condition')['add_col']
for k, v in s.items():
    col = f'on_{k}'
    m = df['event_condition'].eq(k)
    m1 = df['event_condition'].notna()
    df[col] = np.select([m1, m.iloc[::-1].cummax().iloc[::-1]], 
                        [np.nan, df['add_col'].where(m).bfill()], 0)

print (df)
   event_condition  add_col  on_condtion1  on_conditon2
0             None      NaN          10.0          20.0
1             None      NaN          10.0          20.0
2             None      NaN          10.0          20.0
3        condtion1     10.0           NaN           NaN
4             None      NaN           0.0          20.0
5             None      NaN           0.0          20.0
6             None      NaN           0.0          20.0
7        conditon2     20.0           NaN           NaN
8             None      NaN           0.0           0.0
9             None      NaN           0.0           0.0
10            None      NaN           0.0           0.0
```

EDIT: If combine forward and back filling together:

```
condition=[None,None,None,'condtion1',None,None,None,'conditon2',None,None,None]
add_val = [None,None,None,10,None,None,None,20,None,None,None]
add_val1 = [None,None,None,70,None,None,None,50,None,None,None]
df=pd.DataFrame({'event_condition':condition,'add_col':add_val, 'add_col2':add_val1})
print (df)
   event_condition  add_col  add_col2
0             None      NaN       NaN
1             None      NaN       NaN
2             None      NaN       NaN
3        condtion1     10.0      70.0
4             None      NaN       NaN
5             None      NaN       NaN
6             None      NaN       NaN
7        conditon2     20.0      50.0
8             None      NaN       NaN
9             None      NaN       NaN
10            None      NaN       NaN
```

---

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['event_condition']).set_index('event_condition')[['add_col','add_col2']]
print (df1)
                 add_col  add_col2
event_condition                   
condtion1           10.0      70.0
conditon2           20.0      50.0
```

---

```
for k, v in df1['add_col2'].items():
    col = f'on_{k}'
    m = df['event_condition'].eq(k)

    m1 = df['event_condition'].notna()
    df[col] = np.select([m1, m.iloc[::-1].cummax().iloc[::-1]], 
                        [np.nan, df['add_col2'].where(m).bfill()], 
                        df['add_col'].where(m).ffill())

print (df)
   event_condition  add_col  add_col2  on_condtion1  on_conditon2
0             None      NaN       NaN          70.0          50.0
1             None      NaN       NaN          70.0          50.0
2             None      NaN       NaN          70.0          50.0
3        condtion1     10.0      70.0           NaN           NaN
4             None      NaN       NaN          10.0          50.0
5             None      NaN       NaN          10.0          50.0
6             None      NaN       NaN          10.0          50.0
7        conditon2     20.0      50.0           NaN           NaN
8             None      NaN       NaN          10.0          20.0
9             None      NaN       NaN          10.0          20.0
10            None      NaN       NaN          10.0          20.0
```

Comment: Thnaks alot ! just one question : is it possible to use bfill with ffill if we have another condition columns like add_col2 ? so for add_col, we use it for ffill and for add_col2, we want to use it for bfill. I just replace 0 values by the value of add_col2 using bffill

Comment: @stat_man - Is possible change data sample?

Comment: Yes, of course. You mean you want to modify something in my sample dataset?

Comment: @stat_man - Working for solution, give me a minute

Comment: @stat_man - Added EDIT1, is it what you need?

Comment: Yes ! Thanks very much. I really appreciate your help. I learned alot